# Smarty: how to include php in template?

Tags: php, smarty

I've tried `{include_php file="phpfile.php"}` and `{php}` tags but both cause deprecated error. Can you not do this in Smarty anymore? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: You should avoid including PHP in templates.

Comment: So how do I do this. I just need php logic somehow

Comment: Execute it in your PHP files and assign it as a template var.

Answer (score 2):

I circumvented this problem. Create a plugin file named `block.php_code.php` with this function in it:

```
function smarty_block_php_code($params, $content, &$smarty)
{
    if (is_null($content))
    {
        return;
    }
    if ('<?php' == substr($content,0,5) && '?>' == substr($content, -2))
        $content = substr($content,5,-2);
    ob_start();
    eval($content);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

In your template, you can then write:

```
{php_code}{literal}<?php

    print "Hello, world!";

?>{/literal}{/php_code}
```

Comment: yoda-style is ugly. especially in a case where it doesn't have *any* advantages

Comment: where would it have advantages in your opinion?

Comment: @wonk0 [This would be an advantage.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624536/which-one-will-execute-faster-if-flag-0-or-if-0-flag/4624562#4624562)

Comment: yes, poor reading; of course it makes more sense if a variable is part of the expression; but IMO you either use yoda-style or you don't; you just don't switch for every condition

Answer (score 2):

They are depreciated for a reason as they allow poor practices. Smarty recommends putting the included script into the PHP logic or creating a [plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl) (which is simple).

> {php} tags are deprecated from Smarty, and should not be used. Put your PHP logic in PHP scripts or plugin functions instead.

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl)

> {include_php} is deprecated from Smarty, use registered plugins to properly insulate presentation from the application code.

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl)

If you include what you are trying to do in your `phpfile.php`, we can help you write a plugin function.

Answer (score 0):

{include_php} is marked as deprecated in both Smarty2 and 3; {php} in Smarty3 only:

- http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.php.tpl
- http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl
- http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl